# Keyboard height incorrect on iPad

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIView` pinned to the bottom of my `superview`. This has a text view in that becomes a first responder when tapped on. At this point I detect that the keyboard will show and change its bottom constraint to move it up so that it's positioned above the keyboard. I use the following code to do so:

```
private func keyboardWillShow(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    guard let info = (aNotification as NSNotification).userInfo,
        let endFrame = (info as NSDictionary).value(forKey: UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey),
        let currentKeyboard = (endFrame as AnyObject).cgRectValue,
        let rate = info[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
        else { return }

    let convertedFrame = self.view.convert(currentKeyboard, from: UIScreen.main.coordinateSpace)
    bottomConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.height - convertedFrame.origin.y

    UIView.animate(withDuration: rate.doubleValue) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

This works fine on the iPhone. However, on an iPad it seems to be moved up double the height that it should be. Why is this?

Comment: show convert function please

Comment: @Scriptable the convert function is Apple's own: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicoordinatespace/1622564-convert

Comment: Ahh! I wasn't aware of that method. I've obviously never used it but also never had the need to, I usually move my view upwards with the keyboard.

Comment: func convert(_ point: CGPoint, 
        from view: UIView?) -> CGPoint .Converts a point from the coordinate system of a given view to that of the receiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When converting a keyboard's frame, you should pass `nil` to the `from` parameter. That properly converts from the window coordinates (as stated in the `UIView convert` documentation).

Your code would also be simpler if you avoid all of the Objective-C coding.

```
private func keyboardWillShow(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    guard let info = aNotification.userInfo,
        let endFrame = info[UIWindow.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue,
        let rate = info[UIWindow.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
        else { return }

    let currentKeyboard = endFrame.cgRectValue
    let convertedFrame = self.view.convert(currentKeyboard, from: nil)
    bottomConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.height - convertedFrame.origin.y

    UIView.animate(withDuration: rate.doubleValue) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```